# How to write vertical sentences in libre office writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to know how to type sentences vertically in libreoffice word and libreoffice impress, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open writer, and click on Format --> Character

[image]

Then go to the Position Tab, and Click on 270 degrees

[image]

And text will be vertical

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Impress, you can try to use the rotation tool in the lower bar.

Execute it onto the text and rotate it by 90 degree.

I do not know if this function is available in LibreOffice Writer.

But I know that in OpenOffice there was such a function with which you could type in vertical text directly.